# Previous and Next Button to load String out of Array in WebView

Tags: java, android, arrays, webview

I have an Array of Websites in my code. 
I added 2 buttons with the id `button1` and `button2`. 
They shall be used to navigate between the sites in Array.

```
private WebView webv;
    private SeekBar seitenSwitcher;
    private String[] websites = {
            "000.htm",
            "001.htm",
            "002.htm",
            "003.htm",
            "004.htm",
            "005.htm",
            "006.htm",
            "007.htm",
            "008.htm",
            "009.htm",
            "010.htm",
            "011.htm",
            "012.htm",
            "013.htm",
            "014.htm",
            "015.htm",
            "016.htm",
    };



    public int pRog;



    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.Viewing);
        webv.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webv.loadUrl(websites[0]);
        pRog = 0;







        Button button1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webv.loadUrl(websites[pRog--]);
                pRog = pRog--; /** I can also leave this out and it works **/



            }
        });

        Button button2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                webv.loadUrl(websites[pRog++]);



            }
        });
```

The idea was that the int `pRog` is used to have the value of the string out of the array websites, which is currently shown.
And then with  "`pRog = pRog--`" or "`pRog = pRog++`" change the value, to fit the currently shown string in the array.

It is working, but not as it should. I can go forward and backward, but the first touch of the button in the other way is not working.

Example:

I start at 000.htm, as you can see in the code. 
First touch of button2. (nothing happens)
Second touch of button2. (webView loads 001.htm) 
Third touch of button2. (webView loads 002.htm) 
Fourth touch of button2. (webView load 003.htm)

First touch of button1. (webView loads 004.htm ! Instead of 002.htm) 
Second touch of button1. (webView loads 003.htm ! now it is working.)

Touch of button2. (web View loads 002.htm ! Down instead of up) 
Afterwards it also works again.)

It also works if i leave out `pRog = pRog++ or --`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do

`webv.loadUrl(websites[++pRog])`

not `webv.loadUrl(websites[pRog++])`

Same for the other button with --

Comment: Shame on me.. Thank you. But why can i let out the line pRog == ++pRog ?